# sort the order X axis

Tags: r

```
library(stringr)
DF <- data.frame(group = c("SL", "AUS", "Italy"),
day1    =   c(1 ,   4   ,   58),
day2    =   c(2 ,   4   ,   78),
day3    =   c(2 ,   6   ,   72),
day4    =   c(5 ,   14  ,   94),
day5    =   c(7 ,   7   ,   147),
day6    =   c(10,   3   ,   185),
day7    =   c(15,   11  ,   234),
day8    =   c(9 ,   9   ,   573),
day9    =   c(8 ,   10  ,   335),
day10   =   c(12,   23  ,   446),
day11   =   c(6 ,   12  ,   587),
day12   =   c(9 ,   28  ,   769),
day13   =   c(10,   43  ,   778),
day14   =   c(5 ,   49  ,   1247),
day15   =   c(0 ,   52  ,   1492),
day16   =   c(4 ,   101 ,   1797),
day17   =   c(0 ,   54  ,   977),
day18   =   c(9 ,   141 ,   2313),
day19   =   c(2 ,   160 ,   2651),
day20   =   c(5 ,   172 ,   2547),
day21   =   c(21,   144 ,   3497),
day22   =   c(3 ,   537 ,   3590),
day23   =   c(5 ,   278 ,   3223),
day24   =   c(8 ,   430 ,   3526),
day25   =   c(7 ,   359 ,   4207))
DFtall <- str_sort(DF, numeric = TRUE)) %>% gather(key = Day, value = Value, day1:day25)
print(DFtall)
ggplot(DFtall, aes(Day, Value, fill = group)) + geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

I am very much new to Rstudio and now am facing an issue when try to bar graph.
Although the above code provides me a bar chart,
Out put of X axis is = day1 , day10,day 11, day 2 whereas it should be day1,day2,day10,day11

With that said, can somebody help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Day` column is to be treated as a categorical column in R. As such it would need to know "some order" for sorting (it is generally not inferred in the dataset). To set it explicitly, you would use the `factor` function.

Using your code it would look like this:

```r
DFtall <- DF %>% gather(key = Day, value = Value, day1:day25)
DFtall$Day <- factor(DFtall$Day, levels=unique(DFtall$Day))
ggplot(DFtall, aes(Day, Value, fill = group)) + geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

Order can be explicitly set as well if you have a custom ordering in the `levels` argument. See also: https://r4ds.had.co.nz/factors.html

Comment: can you please help suggesting that what need to be done , if need to fit Cubic / exponential regression model in this scenario